# Ember / PostCSS / Tailwind - where do directives get parsed?

Tags: ember.js, postcss, tailwind-css

I've assembled a vanilla combination of ember, postcss, and tailwind, and for the life of me, I cannot understand why this code works.

For a generic ember app with postcss and tailwind:

```
ember new poc-tailwind --yarn
ember install ember-cli-postcss
yarn add tailwindcs
```

Then to configure postcss in ember-cli-build:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    postcssOptions: {
      compile: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss')
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

And then finally in app.css:

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

Again, the strange thing is this *works*.

Can anyone explain why those directives are working? And how they're getting glued together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, all the "magic" is happening here:

https://github.com/jeffjewiss/ember-cli-postcss/blob/58eb75fd351a73c1cea6ea40cfd7425659e6ac44/index.js

Basically, this file uses ember-cli hooks to customize the build process so that postcss preprocesses your CSS files using the plugin you specified (tailwindcs).

The code in this file also allows for postprocessing and filtering, although you aren't using those features.

The directives are parsed and executed at build time by postcss, pure CSS is delivered to your browser.

You don't need to understand everything that is going on in this file, just know that the code is there and open source, in case you need it.

Unlike module bundlers like parcel and webpack, ember-cli and broccoli rely on JavaScript code to do most configuration, rather than configuration files. Combined with convention over configuration, this can make ember-cli feel like "magic".

Comment: Awesome - thank you! I think the other thing I had failed to understand was that the directives (i.e. `@tailwind components;`) were written by tailwind with the explicit intension of being used by postcss.